# Sharepoint-customizing usercontrol property in smartpart

Tags: sharepoint, user-controls, web-parts, smartpart

If anyone is having idea how to customize properties in a smartpart. I have created usercontrol and i m wrappin it in a smartpart.I want to upload my xml from Document library.

```
private string feedXML;
        [Browsable(true),
        Personalizable(true) ]


        public string FeedXML
        {
            get
            { return feedXML; }

            set
            { feedXML = value; }
        }
```

and I am using this like
     //

```
feedXML="\customxml.xml";
    XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(Server.MapPath(feedXML));
```

but this thing is not working . When I am clicking on modify shared webpart of sharepoint page is not rendering. Any clue where I m getting wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to verify the result of your server.mappath statement. It will be something like C:\Inetpub... 
So your code is trying to retrieve a file from the filesystem that really lives in SharePoint because you have uploaded it to a Document Library.

If you want that file you'll have to retrieve it using the SharePoint object model, have a look at the [GetFileAsString method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getfileasstring.aspx).

I agree with Denni..

Seems like Smartpart is only making it more difficult? What advantages does it have?

I make my own webpart containers for ascx controls.. very little work and all the control you need. No problems with trust settings either.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is correct?

```
feedXML="\customxml.xml";
```

Perhaps, what you want is:

```
feedXML="\\customxml.xml"; //escape the back-slash.
```

or

```
feedXML="/customxml.xml"; // use the forward-slash.
```

Anyway, if you just want to wrap your user control inside a Web part, you don't need the SmartPart. You can write your custom Web part yourself quite easily.

Comment: Thanks Denni for replying the thing is we r using Smartpart bcoz of its ease of use with usercontrols I know we can do it other way but SmartPart has other advantages....No I tried the way u r saying but its still the same ...Page is not reendering when I m clicking on modify shared webpart of smartpart ....means do u hv any idea how to do it...Do i need to use SmartPart.Iusercontrol for it...and define properties...or I can do the same way in usercontrol the  i do in webpart and it will reflect in my smartpart